# Как наиболее эффективно читать последнюю строку активно обновляющегося лога с помощью C?

Tags: c, логирование

Допустимы внешние зависимости от Windows 10.

Comment: Пока вы используете термины "строка" и пытаетесь их(строки)  упорядочить как цельную единую сущность - никак. Строка понятие чисто виртуальное. Подумайте как описать задачу без "абстрактных" терминов, или перестаньте гоняться за скоростью, скорость и абстракция - противоположные вещи.

Comment: Тогда если конкретно, то вывести очередность символов между последним /n в файле и EOF и желательно делать это каждый раз при обновлении файла.

Comment: Читаете достаточно большой (несколько килобайт) блок с конца файла и ищете там предпоследний '\n' (просматривая данные от конца к началу). Поскольу обычно строки короткие (несколько десятков символов), то этот поиск не займет много времени

Comment: С последнего чтения запоминайте позицию после прочтения последней строки. В следующем чтении читайте от этой позиции до конца файла. Но это всё работает только в том случае, если лог только увеличивается.